# Unknown reference to GWT widget prevents clearing of detached DOM tree

Tags: dom, gwt, google-chrome-devtools

I've got a GWT 2.4 app where I'm "swapping views" by switching out one `Composite` widget on the `RootPanel` for another, using the usual `RootPanel.get().clear()` and `RootPanel.get().add(newWidget)` to remove and add, respectively.

The first composite widget contains a `PasswordTextBox`.  It listens for the Enter keypress, which triggers the swap.  Nothing too fancy:

```
getDisplay().getPasswordBoxForKeyPresses().addKeyPressHandler(new KeyPressHandler() {
    public void onKeyPress(KeyPressEvent event) {
        if (event.getNativeEvent().getKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER) {
            swapWidgets(); // clear RootPanel and add new widget
        }
    }
});
```

The problem is that there is a DOM memory leak: after `RootPanel.get().clear()` is called, the old composite widget is stuck in the detached DOM tree because the `HTMLInputElement` for the `PasswordTextBox` has some strange reference to it which I cannot identify.

**Update:**
I took the helpful advice below, compiled at style=detailed and started trying to drive down the tree to look a reference to the element in JS.  I'm pretty new with GWT, so it still isn't obvious to me what's going on.  So starting with the second line in the retaining tree, I can see that `lastEvent` in `_2` contains the `nativeKeyTarget` listed at the top of tree.  But where do I go from there?
[image]

Comment: Why not keep following the retaining tree portion of the dialog to see where it is stored? Compiled with style=PRETTY and you'll be able to read the compiled GWT code, and see what the other variables/fields are. Keep expanding the items to see when it hooks back into your app or into some library you may be using, and post those results if you can't yet figure out what is going on.

Comment: You mention, that the PasswordTextBox is a part of Composite 1? Then it's not strange at all, that it has a (parent) reference to Composite 1. => As long as you keep a reference to your PasswordTextBox somewhere in your code, you won't get rid of Composite 1.

Comment: @ChrisLercher I agree...there must be reference somewhere.  As far as I can tell, the presenter for the Composite1 widget (which is actually a view-widget hybrid) has passed out of scope.  That's the only place I can think of that would hold a reference to the PasswordTextBox.

Comment: @ColinAlworth Good idea.  I'll start digging and update the original post with the retaining tree data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tracked the reference down to SmartGWT.  It tracks the last click event within ISC_Core.js.  Further questions are

1. How will this behavior further affect memory usage in my app?
2. Can this behavior be bypassed if need be?

But those questions are for another post!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may not be tracking the handler registrations which will cause memory leaks, prevent objects from being recovered, and cause phantom event captures.

In pure GWT, it looks like this

```
// class member
HandlerRegistration reg;

// save for recovery
reg = getDisplay().getPasswordBoxForKeyPresses().addKeyPressHandler(...);

public void onDetatch() {
// recover memory
reg.removeHandler();
reg = null;
}
```

GXT has a nice grouping feature to prevent registration sprawl, it looks like this

```
// class member
GroupingHandlerRegistration regs = new GroupingHandlerRegistration();
// save for later recovery
regs.add( getDisplay().getPasswordBoxForKeyPresses().addKeyPressHandler(...) );
// recover memory
regs.removeHandler();
```

[Source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sencha.gxt/gxt/3.0.0-beta1/com/sencha/gxt/core/shared/event/GroupingHandlerRegistration.java) for GroupingHandlerRegistration